# Cannot extract data from firebase snapshot

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a very basic firebase database filled with movies. It's basically the movie title, its year and genre as shown below

[image: db]

I also have a class for these 3 attributes of each key.
All I want to do is take the data from the firebase snapshot and put it inside my object.

What I did was:

1. Initialize the database for the child "Filme":

   ```
   DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Filme");
   ```
2. Then I added an ValueEvent Listener:

   ```
   database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



               for (DataSnapshot keyNode : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
               {


                   Filme nfilme = keyNode.getValue(Filme.class);
                   String s = nfilme.getTituloFilme(); // get title

               }
   ```

The debugger shows the line:

```
DataSnapshot { key = 001, value = {Genero=Drama, Titulo=Titanic, Ano=2000} }
```

Which shows that it was able to extract the data, however when I call the getTitle() method it returns null, why is this happening?

EDIT: class added

```
public class Filme {
    private String tituloFilme;
    private String genero;
    private String ano;

    public Filme(){

    }

    public Filme(String tituloFilme, String genero, String ano){
        this.tituloFilme = tituloFilme;
        this.genero = genero;
        this.ano = ano;
    }
    public String getTituloFilme() {
        return tituloFilme;
    }

    public void setTituloFilme(String tituloFilme) {
        this.tituloFilme = tituloFilme;
    }

    public String getGenero() {
        return genero;
    }

    public void setGenero(String genero) {
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    public String getAno() {
        return ano;
    }

    public void setAno(String ano) {
        this.ano = ano;
    }
}
```

Plus, if I use:

```
database.child("001").child("Titulo").setValue("TTITANIC");
```

It does change the title from Titanic, to TTITANIC, so I don't think it has something to do with  the JSON file

Comment: Value does not look to be a valid JSON object. I would expect : instead of  =. Can you show your getTitle() method?

Comment: @Bromox it's just a class named "movie" with 3 attributes one of them being title, with a method getTitle which returns title. That's about it not really worth adding it here I guess

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the `Filme` class? My first guess is that there's some mistake in the mapping of the properties.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just added it

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebase/main/profile/movies) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase uses JavaBean property naming conventions for its JSON to Java conversions (and vice versa).

This means that (for example)  `public String getTituloFilme()` in your code, maps to a property `tituloFilme` in the JSON. That mismatches on two fronts with your actual database:

1. There is no `Filme` suffix in your database.
2. The property in the database is `Titulo`, while the Java class expects `titulo`.

The easiest way to fix this is to specify type annotations in your Java class to explicitly map to specific JSON properties:

```
public class Filme {
    private String tituloFilme;
    private String genero;
    private String ano;

    public Filme(){ }

    public Filme(String tituloFilme, String genero, String ano){
        this.tituloFilme = tituloFilme;
        this.genero = genero;
        this.ano = ano;
    }
    @PropertyName("Titulo")
    public String getTituloFilme() {
        return tituloFilme;
    }

    @PropertyName("Titulo")
    public void setTituloFilme(String tituloFilme) {
        this.tituloFilme = tituloFilme;
    }

    @PropertyName("Genero")
    public String getGenero() {
        return genero;
    }

    @PropertyName("Genero")
    public void setGenero(String genero) {
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    @PropertyName("Ano")
    public String getAno() {
        return ano;
    }

    @PropertyName("Ano")
    public void setAno(String ano) {
        this.ano = ano;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work either.

Comment: "it didn't work" is hard to help with. We'll need more debug info in that case, as this was most certain a reason why your code won't work. When you log `keyNode.getKey()` and  and `keyNode.child("Titulo").getValue()`, what values are logged?

Comment: Sorry, I just added more information. Im able to change the value of title, but I cannot read somehow

Comment: Frank, you're right using String s = keyNode.child("Titulo").getValue(String.class) gets me the title, BUT what I wanted was to read everything under 001, i.e the whole movie information inside the movie class rather than each individual attribute.

Comment: I know what your goal was, this was just for debugging, to determine if your `keyNode` is on the right level in the JSON.  Since it is, the property names are really the most likely cause of the problem. Are you sure you applied them correctly, as shown in my answer?

Comment: @Luis Any update?

Comment: Hey @Luis. Any update here?

Comment: yes sorry for the wait the problem  ended up being that I should've written all the code INSIDE the onDataChange method, I left some of it outside the function and that was the culprit apparently.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this simple if

```java
database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



            for (DataSnapshot keyNode : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {

                if(keyNode.getKey().equals("Titulo")){
                    Filme nfilme = keyNode.getValue();
                    //do what you want
                }
            }
```

if thats not gonna work then, try to add another snapshot

```java
database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



            for (DataSnapshot keyNode : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                for(DataSnapshot child2 : keyNode.getChildren()){

                    if(keyNode.getKey().equals("Titulo")){
                        Filme nfilme = keyNode.getValue();
                        //do what you want
                    }
                }
            }
```

don't forget to use `toString()` method

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work unfortunately

Comment: @Luis what is log says?

Comment: The problem, I think is, I'm extracting the data alright, as the debugger shows, the problem is extracting the data INTO the class

Comment: into Filmed class?

Comment: yes into the Film class

Comment: ur film class is ok